# call grandparent method without calling parent and without modifying parent/grandparent

Tags: php, overriding, prestashop

I found myself in this situation and I just hacked it dirtily. But I wonder, is there some clean way?

```
class base{
    var $value;
    public function getValue(){
        return 'returned from base: '. $value;
    }
}

class object extends base{
    public function getValue(){
        $this->value = 'wrong value';
        return parent::getValue();
    }
}


class overwrite extends object{
    public function getValue(){
        $this->value = 'right value';

        ?????

    }
}

$o = new overwrite;
echo $o->getValue();
```

All I'm allowed to edit is `overwrite`. If I call `parent::getValue()`, the value gets overwritten by wrong value. If I name the class, like `base::getValue()`, the base class would not have `$value` property set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out before I finished the question, but I decided to post it anyway:

base::getValue() seems to be the correct solution, php seems to do some magic there, so `base` class has `$value` property set, when called from its child.